# How add a CSS Jelly file to Jenkins Plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

I have made my own stylesheet that I require to include on the Jenkins plugin.

```
   <l:layout css="/plugin/myPlugin/css/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${rootURL}/plugin/myPlugin/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Please advice me..

Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To link CSS files in Jelly files is deprecated, [see jelly tags documentation](https://jenkins-ci.org/maven-site/jenkins-core/jelly-taglib-ref.html#isAdminOrTest):

```
This was originally added to allow plugins to load their stylesheets, but the use of thie 
attribute is discouraged now. plugins should now do so by inserting <style> elements 
and/or <script> elements in <l:header/> tag.
```

Please use inline css tags instead ([code example](https://github.com/jenkinsci/sloccount-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/tabview/css.jelly)).

Answer (score 2):

Place your css file(s) under

> /src/webapp/css

and reference them as ..

> " href="${rootURL}/plugin//css/layout.css"

Answer (score 2):

Using a `<link>` element with the $rootURL as noted above worked for me. The important thing that I noticed was to make sure to place the `<link>` element after `<l:layout>`.  I had it right after the `<j:jelly>` tag originally and it wasn't able to render the ${rootURL}.

The `<link>` tag will be much cleaner than doing inline styling.